# Add a little padding to a centered rectangle on the Canvas with a sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I know how to center a rectangle on the Canvas. I have already seen [How do I center a rectangle on a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413594/how-do-i-center-a-rectangle-on-a-canvas) but I also have a `250px` sidebar.

I have the following code:

```
<Rect
  width={browser.width}
  height={browser.height}
  x={(win.width - 250 - browser.width) / 2}
  y={(win.height - browser.height) / 2}
  fill="papayawhip"
/>
```

Where `win.width` equals to `window.innerWidth`, respectively `win.height` equals to `window.innerHeight`.

`browser.width` equals to `win.width - 250` where 250 is my sidebar width.

I did [what the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48413649/6141587) said `canvasWidth/2 - rectangleWidth/2`. My `canvasWidth` is `win.width - 250` & `rectangleWidth` is `browser.width`.

How do I add a little padding to the `papayawhip` rectangle?

Here's a minimal Codesandbox → https://codesandbox.io/s/add-padding-to-centered-canvas-with-sidebar-gqhhl

[image: center papayawhip]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer while framing the question so I'll just post it.

I had to make a `pad` variable & subtract it from rectangle width & add the half of it to `x` position like:

```
const pad = 50
<Rect
  width={browser.width - pad}
  height={browser.height}
  x={pad / 2}
  y={(win.height - browser.height) / 2}
  fill="papayawhip"
/>
```

[image: add little padding on either side of canvas]