# How to center the "fillRect" -methode relative to canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to center the blue rectangle made with fillrec relative to the size of the canvas (aqua). I didnt find a solution yet, due to my newbie knowledge working with JS. And my little research and trying things out didn't help either. I was hoping for a little guidance regarding that matter.

```css
canvas {
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<html> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="canvas.css">
    <body>
        <canvas width="800", height="800", id="1"   > </canvas>
        <script>

            let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
            let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            context.fillStyle = "Blue"
            context.fillRect(15, 15, 400, 400);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhhh if you canvas is always 800 and that square always 400 you can do

```
context.fillRect(200, 200, 400, 400);
```

It just plus and minus
Or you can check this out
[How do I center a rectangle on a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413594/how-do-i-center-a-rectangle-on-a-canvas)

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the link. It helped me find the answer to my question.